# Handle 404 exception in ASP.Net web API

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

I have ASP.Net web API in .net framework 4.8.
I have implemented single sign on using Azure active directory bearer token.
User will be redirected to login page if route is found in routing table. However, if user enters incorrect route (https://mysite/invalidurl) then it directly shows a yellow death screen with 404.

**Is it possible to redirect user to login page first incase of invalid url (404) also? If yes then how? It means user enters any url (valid or invalid), s/he should be redirected to login page first.**

I have already tried few options but none of the option worked for me like ExceptionHandler, AttributeRouting, CustomError in Web.Config, Application_Error in global.asax, global pattern matching in route table ( like this: routeTemplate: "api/{*uri}",)

Here is the code of my startup file

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            List<string> audiences = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"].Split(AudienceDelimitter).ToList();

            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

       

 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
            new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "OAuth2Bearer",
                Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"],
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidAudiences = audiences
                }
            });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                RedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri
            });
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Presumably you're talking about your web page authentication through a login page - but your code is the webapi back-end authentication configuration which has nothing to do with showing a login screen surely ? Please show your UI code.

Comment: @auburg we don't have UI. To access any resources of api, user has to get the token first through redirection to login page. E.g. http://domain/invalidurl. Here user can also directly hit the url in browser for get method

Comment: I think you're confusing things - your web api expects a valid bearer token. If you have a website that talks to your API and users login to authenticate themselves then you'll have access to the bearer token that way. If you want users to be redirected to your websites login page whenever they access a valid / invalid page then that's  where you configure that behaviour. If you do not have a web page then it makes no sense speaking about login pages - whatever that's calling your webapi needs to acquire a token programmatically (presumably using a secret).